# What does partisan lens mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found the expression **partisan lens** in this sentence

> And the Mayor of Miami speaks for many when he says it is long past time this can be viewed through a **partisan lens**.

Well, I found out that a partisan is an unthinking supporter of a political faction who blindly adhere to faction's positions.

But what does exactly partisan lens mean? Does it mean that it is an unthinking and fascistic perspective?

Comment: From the eyes of a partisan, perhaps. Like we have lens in our eyes, on similar terms, from the part of view of a partisan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real lens bends light and can make things look bigger or distort them.

A partisan is a supporter of a cause (not necessarily an unthinking one)

Figuratively "viewing through an XXX lens" is "seeing and understanding the world in the (distorted) way that XXX people do".  So viewed through a partisan lens means "seen how partisans would see it".

I guess the suggestion is that the mayor is a partisan (a Republican, even though officially the mayoral role is non-partisan) and so you should remember that he has a particular opinion and is trying to get the best result for his "side".

Comment: thank you for your answer @James K. Actually, I think now the meaning of the sentence is that it is a long past time this could be understood and seen in the way partisans do. And for the definition of partisan to be honest, I consulted https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103574/advocate-versus-partisan